# Python strip \n tabs from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have the following string which includes time and date along with \n with numbers. I want only date time value.
Input:

```
str1 = '1    2016-04-30 00:30:00\n2    2016-04-30 02:00:00\n3    2016-04-30 02:00:00\n4    2016-04-30 03:16:00\n5    2016-04-30 08:27:18\n6    2016-04-30 10:10:00\n7    2016-04-30 10:27:00\n8    2016-04-30 13:00:00\n9    2016-04-30 14:00:00\n10   2016-04-30 16:00:00\n11   2016-04-30 16:30:00\n12   2016-04-30 16:30:00\n13   2016-04-30 17:18:00\n14   2016-04-30 19:00:00\n15   2016-04-30 19:30:00\n16   2016-04-30 22:00:00\n17   2016-04-30 23:12:00\n18   2016-04-30 23:30:00\n19   2016-04-30 23:50:00\n20   2016-04-30 23:50:00\n21   2016-04-30 23:50:00\nName: CrimeDate, dtype: datetime64[ns]'
```

output:

```
'2016-04-30 00:30:00,2016-04-30 02:00:00,2016-04-30 02:00:00,2016-04-30 03:16:00,2016-04-30 08:27:18,2016-04-30 10:10:00,2016-04-30 10:27:00,2016-04-30 13:00:00,2016-04-30 14:00:00,2016-04-30 16:00:00,2016-04-30 16:30:00,2016-04-30 16:30:00,2016-04-30 17:18:00,2016-04-30 19:00:00,2016-04-30 19:30:00,2016-04-30 22:00:00,2016-04-30 23:12:00,2016-04-30 23:30:00,2016-04-30 23:50:00,2016-04-30 23:50:00,2016-04-30 23:50:00'
```

I have tried the following ways to fix the problem:

```
str1 = str1.split(',')[0]
ini_string=' '.join(str1.split())[0:-16]
res = ini_string.replace(' ', ',')
```

but this is not working. Is there any better way to get the desired results.
I am doing this in python 3.

Comment: You appear to have a `pandas.DataFrame` therefore you should try to use `pandas` operations to perform the conversion. See [my suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66487543/21945) for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would keep it simple here and just use `re.findall`:

```py
str1 = '1    2016-04-30 00:30:00\n2    2016-04-30 02:00:00\n3    2016-04-30 02:00:00\n4    2016-04-30 03:16:00\n5    2016-04-30 08:27:18\n6    2016-04-30 10:10:00\n7    2016-04-30 10:27:00\n8    2016-04-30 13:00:00\n9    2016-04-30 14:00:00\n10   2016-04-30 16:00:00\n11   2016-04-30 16:30:00\n12   2016-04-30 16:30:00\n13   2016-04-30 17:18:00\n14   2016-04-30 19:00:00\n15   2016-04-30 19:30:00\n16   2016-04-30 22:00:00\n17   2016-04-30 23:12:00\n18   2016-04-30 23:30:00\n19   2016-04-30 23:50:00\n20   2016-04-30 23:50:00\n21   2016-04-30 23:50:00\nName: CrimeDate, dtype: datetime64[ns]'
matches = re.findall(r'\b\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\b', str1)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['2016-04-30 00:30:00', '2016-04-30 02:00:00', '2016-04-30 02:00:00', '2016-04-30 03:16:00',
 '2016-04-30 08:27:18', '2016-04-30 10:10:00', '2016-04-30 10:27:00', '2016-04-30 13:00:00',
 '2016-04-30 14:00:00', '2016-04-30 16:00:00', '2016-04-30 16:30:00', '2016-04-30 16:30:00',
 '2016-04-30 17:18:00', '2016-04-30 19:00:00', '2016-04-30 19:30:00', '2016-04-30 22:00:00',
 '2016-04-30 23:12:00', '2016-04-30 23:30:00', '2016-04-30 23:50:00', '2016-04-30 23:50:00',
 '2016-04-30 23:50:00']
```

Comment: Good answer; I was going to use re.sub, but this is better.

Comment: @TimRoberts `re.split` might also be viable, but there is some junk at the end of the input which would probably interfere.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying ```re.split``` and obviously junk at the end creating some issues. ```re.findall``` is a good approach. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your data is a pandas DataFrame that has been converted to a string. For example you might have done this:

```
>>> str(df['CrimeDate'])
'0    2016-04-30 00:30:00\n1    2016-04-30 02:00:00\n2    2016-04-30 02:00:00\n3    2016-04-30 03:16:00\n4    2016-04-30 08:27:18\n5    2016-04-30 10:10:00\n6    2016-04-30 10:27:00\n7    2016-04-30 13:00:00\n8    2016-04-30 14:00:00\n9    2016-04-30 16:00:00\n10   2016-04-30 16:30:00\n11   2016-04-30 16:30:00\n12   2016-04-30 17:18:00\n13   2016-04-30 19:00:00\n14   2016-04-30 19:30:00\n15   2016-04-30 22:00:00\n16   2016-04-30 23:12:00\n17   2016-04-30 23:30:00\n18   2016-04-30 23:50:00\n19   2016-04-30 23:50:00\n20   2016-04-30 23:50:00\nName: CrimeDate, dtype: datetime64[ns]'
```

Assuming that you have access to the DataFrame you could convert the column to a comma separated list like this:

```
>>> df['CrimeDate'].to_csv(header=False, index=False, line_terminator=',')[:-1]
'2016-04-30 00:30:00,2016-04-30 02:00:00,2016-04-30 02:00:00,2016-04-30 03:16:00,2016-04-30 08:27:18,2016-04-30 10:10:00,2016-04-30 10:27:00,2016-04-30 13:00:00,2016-04-30 14:00:00,2016-04-30 16:00:00,2016-04-30 16:30:00,2016-04-30 16:30:00,2016-04-30 17:18:00,2016-04-30 19:00:00,2016-04-30 19:30:00,2016-04-30 22:00:00,2016-04-30 23:12:00,2016-04-30 23:30:00,2016-04-30 23:50:00,2016-04-30 23:50:00,2016-04-30 23:50:00'
```

The `[:-1]` removes the trailing comma added by `to_csv()`.

Another way would be to use `str.join()`:

```
>>> ','.join(str(dt) for dt in df['CrimeDate'])
```

but the first method avoids iteration over the DataFrame column, keeping the processing in pandas.

Answer (score 0):

```
without_strip = str1.replace("\n", "")
```

> 2016-04-30 00:30:002    2016-04-30 02:00:003    2016-04-30 02:00:004
> 2016-04-30 03:16:005    2016-04-30 08:27:186    2016-04-30 10:10:007
> 2016-04-30 10:27:008    2016-04-30 13:00:009    2016-04-30 14:00:0010
> 2016-04-30 16:00:0011   2016-04-30 16:30:0012   2016-04-30 16:30:0013
> 2016-04-30 17:18:0014   2016-04-30 19:00:0015   2016-04-30 19:30:0016
> 2016-04-30 22:00:0017   2016-04-30 23:12:0018   2016-04-30 23:30:0019
> 2016-04-30 23:50:0020   2016-04-30 23:50:0021   2016-04-30
> 23:50:00Name: CrimeDate, dtype: datetime64[ns]

or to remove the `1` at the beginning.

```
listToStr = ' '.join(map(str, without_strip.split()[1:]))
```